# sort numbers in text file using command prompt

Tags: cmd

I wanted to sort numbers in a text file and write the same in another text file for the same I am using the command given below but I am not able to get the output can someone please help me with the same

```
sort -n test.txt /o output.txt
```

There is an error message coming up for this as Input file specified two times.

Comment: what's `-n` supposed to be?

Comment: It's for sorting numeric.

Comment: windows `sort` does not have such a parameter (see `sort /?`) If you use another implementation of `sort`, please specify.

Comment: I just used sort test.txt /o output.txt still its not working

Comment: define "not working".

Comment: Its giving wrong result my text is 1
100
101
103
107
110
130
131
132
133
134
135
149
152
153
16
17
18
194
195
196
197
198
199
2
200
201
202
224
244
245
246
256
257
258
259
26
260
261
262
263
264
272
273
274
275
28
29
301
32
344
349
350
379
380
388
403
404
411
52
53
85
86
87
90
91
94
97

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88344/discussion-between-anoop-and-stephan).

Comment: found some possibly helpful answers: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28078521/2152082), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7115084/2152082), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25647441/2152082)

Comment: No positive response yet

Answer (score 0):

(nice exercise :) )

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM convert all numbers to the same lenght by adding leading spaces:
(for /f %%i in (input.txt) do (
    REM 12 leading spaces:
    set "Z=            %%i"
    REM take last 12 digits:
    echo !Z:~-12!
))>temp.txt 

REM sort it:'
sort temp.txt /O temp.txt

REM remove the spaces:
(for /f %%i in (temp.txt) do echo/%%i)>output.txt
del temp.txt
```

Comment: define "not working"... Working well here (despite of a typo (corrected))

Comment: I passed a temp file and the output file is blank

Comment: you are supposed to pass `input.txt`. `temp.txt` is (over)written by the code.

Answer (score 0):

For sure ***(nice exercise :) )*** !!!

---

Sort numbers in text file using command prompt **but not using `sort`** command!!**

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion & cd /d "%~dp0" 

for /f delims^=:^ tokens^=^2 %%i in ('find /c /v ";" input.txt')do set _cnt=%%i
2>nul (cd.>"%tmp%\_file_.tmp" & cd.>"output.txt") & for /f %%i in (input.txt)do echo/,%%i,>>"%tmp%\_file_.tmp"
for /l %%L in (1 1 99999)do find ",%%L," "%tmp%\_file_.tmp" >nul && (echo/%%L>>"output.txt" & call set /a "_cnt-=1" && if !_cnt! == 0 goto :~0)

:~0  
timeout -1  & del "%tmp%\_file_.tmp" & type "output.txt"
```

---

```bat
:: to count lines / numbers that exist in the file, too, to be used as a run delimiter in for /l ::
for /f delims^=:^ tokens^=^2 %%i in ('find /c /v ";" input.txt')do set _cnt=%%i

:: create the 2 empty files and if they exist, delete the contents ::
2>nul (cd.>"%tmp%\_file_.tmp" & cd.>"output.txt")

:: create unique string for each file number/line "%tmp%\_file_.tmp" ::
for /f %%i in (input.txt)do echo/,%%i,>>"%tmp%\_file_.tmp"

rem :: performs a 1 in 1 to 99999 numeric loop and also finds ",number," in the file "%tmp%\_file_.tmp" ::
rem :: remove ",," (commas) from string, save (if any), only the variable number %%L in "output.txt"
for /l %%L in (1 1 99999)do find ",%%L," "%tmp%\_file_.tmp" >nul && (echo/%%L>>"output.txt" & call set /a "_cnt-=1" && if !_cnt! == 0 goto :~0)

:: for each occurrence, it will be subtracting 1 from the _cnt counter, so when it reaches zero it stops listing/fetching ::
echo/%%L>>"output.txt" & call set /a "_cnt-=1" && if !_cnt! == 0 goto :~0)
```

Comment: Instead of `delims^=:^ tokens^=^2` you can just do `"tokens=2 delims=:"` (much easier to read). And you don't need commas if you use `findstr /x` (or maybe `findstr "\<%%L\>"` to be safe from stray spaces)

Comment: @Stephan This are using 2 delimiters, “: “ + 1 space!  “: “ and I think the find is more fast and sort them findstr.

Comment: @Stephan let me know you are considering about it, please!

Comment: `"tokens=2 delims=: "` then. I don't know, if `find` is faster than `findstr`, but if it is, the generation of `_file_.tmp` surely negates the advantage.